# Most common adjectives to describe the intensity of drunkenness

Tags: word-usage, word-request, adjectives, colloquial-language

There are several degrees of intensity of drunkenness, ranging from a state of slight euphoria to total oblivion, which may be recognized by the way someone is speaking, moving and behaving.

In the English language, there are so many words (most of them are adjectives) describing different states of inebriation that it seems hardly productive to make any lists classifying all of them according to any criteria.

At the same time, speaking my native language, I don't need more than — let me count — eight colloquial adjectives to say to what degree someone is drunk. As for my second language, I do know some of them, such as *tipsy, tiddly, tight, stoned, loaded* and a few more, but…

Firstly, no dictionary provides sufficient information about the degree of acceptability of these words, depending on the group of people you interact within.

Secondly, I think that like it is in Russian, in English too, there must be a few most common colloquial adjectives that may be appropriate to be used in any company, to describe that someone is  slightly,  fairly, or extremely drunk.

So my question is this:

What might be some  most common adjectives describing  slight, fair, and extreme degrees of inebriation?

Comment: The question is too broad, IMO. There are many such words and phrases.

Comment: @TRomano - I don't need this many, a couple or so adjectives would do fine. I don't need any phrases. What should I do to have it answered, not put on hold as several of my earlier ones were already?

Comment: It is something of a truism that *any* word in the English language can be used as a euphemism for drunk.

Comment: @xxxxxx - I've been there. Now I doubt that I put it clear enough for you to send me there. I'm sorry for that.

Comment: I know what you mean, but this question is both  "too broad" and POB.

Comment: @Chenmunka - Sounds more than intriguing to me? Could you possibly expand on that in your answer I'm so eager to read?

Comment: @xxxxxx - I wish I had something easier to ask, but I need something to answer should someone ask me the like question. In my native language, I think I could - where there's a will, there's a way.

Comment: @xxxxxx  A list containing 100 or more expressions meaning "drunk" does not tell a learner which ones are more common than others. If everyone could provide a shortlist of the "most common" terms, with an explanation, that would be really useful data. Australians have wonderful expressions for example.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Isn't Australia a part of the English-speaking world? I do wish to know those expressions. Would you kindly share a couple or so with me?

Comment: The problem is I don't know how "common" they are. "pissed as a newt" is one I like, but I'm not sure if that is Aussie.

Comment: This should be a community wiki post.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - "Pissed as a newt" is funny, ha-ha. Newts' home grounds are in North America, Europe, and northern Asia, they say. I'm putting it down; thanks.

Comment: Ah, yes. Now we're getting to the *real* things people want to learn when learning a foreign language. Starting with the basics! :P  Looks like you'll have to do some homework with the phrases in the answers. (Get wasted, then use phrases and see if people agree you're at that level of drunkenness). Please report back after a night of getting blitzed and let us know how it went!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In British English the ones I am most familiar with are the following:

1. **[buzzed](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/buzzed)** - (AmE) the person can feel the alcohol, but is still fairly capable of behaving normally and appearing sober. Could also say "I have a *buzz*."
2. **[tipsy](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tipsy)** — the person has drunk sufficient quantities of alcohol to feel "light headed", their head may "tip" backwards or side to side. (I think this may be the origin of the expression)
3. **[merry](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/merry)** — (BrE) often reserved for female drinkers who drink on social occasions. Their inhibitions are loosened, and they may begin giggling, or laughing raucously, it depends on the state of inebriation.
4. **[drunk](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/drunk)** — self explanatory. The person has drunk too much alcohol and their sense of judgement and balance is severely impaired.
5. **[legless](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/legless)** — (BrE) the person is no longer able to stand up, they have lost their legs so to speak.
6. **[plastered](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/plastered), [wasted](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wasted), [hammered](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hammered), [smashed](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/smashed)** — the person will definitely wake up [hung-over](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hung-over), and will probably have lost all recollections of their actions the night before.
7. **[shit-faced](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/shit-faced)** — extremely rude but among friends it can be used. Basically the person's face looks misshapen, i.e. the person is very drunk.

Comment: Oh, thank you, thank you very much! This is the answer I awaited. It perfectly matches my request.

Comment: @Rompey well this is a subjective analysis, some will disagree with me. But have a look at the dictionary definitions and the example sentences  to be absolutely sure.

Comment: @Rompey Are you specifically looking for British English, or American English as well? There's a few more I might add that are common in the US (buzzed, wasted, hammered, black-out)

Comment: All of these are used in AmE except "merry" and "legless". I would add "smashed" around the same level as plastered (and as David K just added while I was typing "hammered").

Comment: Then someone post a shortlist of American English expressions! *Hammered* and *smashed* are also heard in BrEng. Not *buzzed* though,.

Comment: @DavidK - I'm looking for the both. The words you kindly added have all been put down too; thanks a million.

Comment: @ColleenV - Thanks for the feedback. It's been taken note of. Seems like by now, I have quite a list of most common ones. Very much appreciated, really.

Comment: I have never really heard merry or legless in that context but I guess it depends on where you live. Hammered is probably the most common. Or for a level 7 after shit-faced you could use the ever popular "white girl wasted"

Comment: As a speaker of US English, I'd add *falling-down drunk* which means exactly what it sounds like.

Comment: @DavidK you should have posted some American English expressions yourself. But thanks anyway for the edit.

Answer (score 6):

The number of words or phrases that are used as a euphemism for drunk is huge.

Commonly used words vary from place to place and over time.

Indeed, the British comedian [Michael McIntyre](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&site=&source=hp&q=michael+mcintyre) has a 10 minute set that pokes fun at the many and different words that are used.  (On YouTube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0qh0dmW44EA))

In short, you can use pretty much any word(s) you like.  You will be understood.

If you want specific, current, common words used in different localities, then the answer would provide a whole book.

Comment: Thanks awfully. It's a pity the video you gave the link to lasts only one minute; although the main concept was voiced in it. LOL

Comment: I disagree you can use any word/s and you will be understood. Some are *more common* than others, and some are totally unfamiliar to speakers of different dialects.

Comment: @Rompey: Ahh, I googled the link quickly.  There is probably a better one out there.

Comment: @Mari-LouA:  To a certain exent, that is my point.  Different dialects use different words, but over a huge range.  Where I come from the most common are slarmied, ratted and cut but I could go on and on.

Comment: The ones I have listed are very common in BrEng, and that is my point.

Comment: @Chenmunka - The three from your comment addressed to Mari-Lou A have been taken note of too. Thanks again.